# How to past value from get method into custom method

Tags: cypress

I am finding the way how to get value from get method into custom command.
Code shoud look like this:

cy.get('@alias').customCommand(name)

I know i can send it throw parameter like cy.customCommand('@alias', name), but i would like to use chain and in customCommand get value from previous chained command.

Is it posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out. Look at https://code.i-harness.com/en/docs/cypress/api/cypress-api/custom-commands

by this, you have to add into your custom command option {prevSubject: true} and then method get will past value into first parameter of your custom command.

So:

support/commands.ts

```js
    Cypress.Commands.add('customCommand', { prevSubject: true }, (element, datatable, jqSelection) => {..})
```

support/index.ts

```js
    declare global {
      namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
    
          customCommand(datatable, jqSelection): void
    
        }
      }
    }
```

Your step:

```js
    cy.get('@value').customCommand(datatable, jqselection)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('@alias').then((name) => {
  cy.customCommand(name)
})
```

Comment: yeah it is one good way, but now i will have to write everywhere ".then...", but get method past value into next method in chain, how can i access it withou then? Ok, it is good solution but is there some another? I am finding as clear solution as possible.

Comment: i figured out, i added my answer

Comment: Hey thats great! You were able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I doubt if the second variant works because it mix sync and async code. The schema with Cypress.config is in fact the same as using a local variable to pass the value (which will not work either)

Comment: By my opinion, 2nd solution is bad in my case, you shoud use command for their usage, so Cypress.config() is for set up some settings of cypress, not for pasting variables... yeah it is possible, but in my opinion it is not clear solution

Comment: I removed the second solution from the answer.